# Testing service with $httpBackend in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I'm new to AngularJS and running into some problems with unit testing. I've seen countless examples of mocking $httpBackend calls, but when I do that it won't work unless I also include $rootScope.$apply().

My service:

```
angular.module('myApp.services', ['ngResource'])
  .factory('TestingService', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/v1/values', {}, {
      getValues: {
        method: 'GET'
      }
    });
  }]);
```

My unit test:

```
describe('Testing services', function() {
  beforeEach(module('myApp.services'));

  afterEach(function() {
    inject(function($httpBackend) {
      $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
      $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });
  });

  describe('TestingService', function() {
    it('would be nice to get an explanation for this',
        inject(['$rootScope', '$httpBackend', 'TestingService', 
          function ($rootScope, $httpBackend, testingService) {

          $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/v1/values').respond(100);

          var result = testingService.getValues();
          //$rootScope.$apply();

          $httpBackend.flush();
          expect(result).toBe(100);
          alert(result);
      }])
    );
  });
});
```

When Karma runs the test like this I get:

```
Error: No pending request to flush !
Error: Unsatisfied requests: GET /api/v1/values
```

And if I include the $rootScope.$apply(); I'll get this (and the alert of course also prints out a $promise):

```
Expected { $promise : { then : Function, catch : Function, finally : Function }, $resolved : true } to be 100.
```

Can anyone explain why I need "$rootScope.$apply();" to pass the expectGET?
And why the response is a promise instead of the mock response I've specified?

Comment: The response is not a promise, its the `Resource` object which contains a promise. And you don't need `$rootScope.$apply()` at all. The actual test has to be either of the two ways I [created here in plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NEMXQJgJKB2rkr2QeN69?p=preview). What is disturbing me is that I can replicate your problem where it should pass tests instead.

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem after some sleep. Simple one fortunately.

I'm using Angular version 1.3.0-beta.2, but had an older version for angular-mocks. Updating the versions removes the need for "$root.$apply();".

The updated working test:

```
describe('Testing services', function() {
  beforeEach(function(){
    module('myApp.services');
    this.addMatchers({
      toEqualData: function(expected) {
        return angular.equals(this.actual, expected);
      }
    });
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    inject(function($httpBackend) {
      $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
      $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
    });
  });

  describe('TestingService', function() {
    it('should work',
        inject(['$rootScope', '$httpBackend', 'TestingService', 
          function ($rootScope, $httpBackend, testingService) {

          $httpBackend.expectGET('/api/v1/values').respond( { key: 'value' } );

          var result = testingService.getValues();

          $httpBackend.flush();
          expect(result).toEqualData( { key: 'value' } );
          alert(angular.toJson(result, true));
      }])
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: My plunkr had all the versions correct but still I am unable to assert the response status. Have you tried asserting the status?